# If I have five Win32 static controls, how can I set one of them with a specific foreground color?

Tags: c++, winapi

As far as I can tell, this is not a duplicate question because it's dealing with a collection of static (label) controls. I want to set a foreground color to a specific one that I call in my thin OOP library.

I call a static control a "Label" in my library. This is how I set the color:

```
void Label::setForeColor(const BYTE red, const BYTE green, const BYTE blue)
{
    m_foreColor = RGB(red, green, blue);
}
```

This just sets a COLORRREF that the control should have. I'm having trouble finding a solution to send a message for that specific static control without affecting others.

Many say to use WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, but I already am for transparency of controls:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: 
{
    char  class_Name[100];
    WNDCLASS lpcls{};

    SetBkMode((HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT);
    // SetTextColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(0, 0, 255));  This works and can set all statics as blue, but I need just one control blue.        
    GetClassName(hWnd, class_Name, 100); 
    GetClassInfo(frm.getInstance(), class_Name, &lpcls);

    return  (LRESULT)lpcls.hbrBackground;
}
```

But here's the issue: I may have more than one label on a window, so this goes beyond than just setting a single label as most examples show. There may be 5 labels with 5 different colors.

This is the top layer:

```
Label lblName("This is a label.", 330, 303);
lblName.setVisible(true);  
lblName.setForeColor(0, 0, 255);
lblName.setFont("Garamond", 24, false, false, false);
lblName.OnMouseOver(lblName_onMouseOver);
```

Ideally, I would like to set the color in my setFont() function by sending a message.

```
bool Label::setFont(const std::string &fontName, const int size, const bool bold,
    const bool italic, const bool underlined)
{
    DWORD dwItalic;
    DWORD dwBold;
    DWORD dwUnderlined;
    SIZE linkSize;
    HFONT old_font;

    dwItalic = (italic) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    dwBold = (bold) ? FW_BOLD : FW_DONTCARE;
    dwUnderlined = (underlined) ? TRUE : FALSE;

    m_font = CreateFont(size, 0, 0, 0, dwBold, dwItalic, dwUnderlined, FALSE,
        ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY,
        DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS, fontName.c_str());

    SendMessage(m_handle, WM_SETFONT, WPARAM(m_font), TRUE);

    // Calculate the correct width and height size  
    HDC hDC = GetDC(m_handle); 
    old_font = SelectFont(hDC, m_font);   
    GetTextExtentPoint32(hDC, m_text.c_str(), (int)m_text.length(), &linkSize);
    setSize(linkSize.cx, size);  
    DeleteFont(old_font); 
    ReleaseDC(m_handle, hDC); 

    return true;
}
```

Finally, this is how I retrieve my labels that I'm interested in. I wonder if I need to set the font color similarly.

```
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        X3D::Windows::Control *ctrl = (X3D::Windows::Control*) dwRefData;

        // Check if this is a X3D Label control.
        X3D::Windows::Label *lbl = dynamic_cast<X3D::Windows::Label*>(ctrl);
        if (lbl)
        {
            lbl->setHovering(true);
            lbl->invokeOnMouseHover();
        }
        else
        {
            lbl->setHovering(false);
        }
        break;
    }
```

Overall question: If I have five Win32 static controls, how can I set one of them with a specific foreground color?

**Update:**

This is my current code. Assert() is barking at me: Expression: map/set iterator not dereferencable

```
case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: 
{
    char  class_Name[100];
    WNDCLASS lpcls{};

    SetBkMode((HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT);

    GetClassName(hWnd, class_Name, 100); 
    GetClassInfo(frm.getInstance(), class_Name, &lpcls);

    for (int i = 0; i < frm.getControlCount(); i++)
    {
        if (frm.getControls().find(i)->second->getHandle() == (HWND)lParam)
        {

            // Obtain the control associated with the id.
            X3D::Windows::Control *ctrl = frm.getControls().find(i)->second;
            if (ctrl == NULL)
                return 0;

            // Check if this is a X3D Label control. 
            Label *lbl = dynamic_cast<X3D::Windows::Label*>(ctrl);

            if (lbl != NULL)
            {
                SetTextColor((HDC)wParam, lbl->getForeColor());
                break;
            }  
        }
    } 

    return  (LRESULT)lpcls.hbrBackground;
}
```

**Update:**
App runs, but the font color isn't updating. Something wrong in this?

```
    int id = GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam);

        // Obtain the control associated with the id.
    X3D::Windows::Control *ctrl = frm.getControls().at(id);
        if (ctrl == NULL)
            return 0;

        // Check if this is a X3D Label control. 
        Label *lbl = dynamic_cast<X3D::Windows::Label*>(ctrl);

        if (lbl != NULL)
        {
            SetTextColor((HDC)wParam, lbl->getForeColor());
            break;
        }
```

Tried this too:

```
    int id = GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam);

        // Obtain the control associated with the id.
    X3D::Windows::Control *ctrl = frm.getControls().find(id)->second;
        if (ctrl == NULL)
            return 0;
```

If all of that looks correct, I'll just have to debug it tomorrow.

Comment: Don't call `find(i)` multiple times.  In fact, if you are looping through all the controls, don't use `find()` at all, a ranged-for (`for(auto& child : frm.getControls())`) will be far far more efficient.  When you do have a good reason to use `find()`, check its return value against `end()` to see if it didn't match.

Comment: I agree. My goal right now is to get it to work and optimize afterwards.

Comment: ranged-for will be easier to make work

Comment: I haven't tried that before. I'll try it.

Comment: If you want to eliminate the loop, you can look up the ID (at least, your other question seems to use the ID as the map key, not just a counter which your code here tries).  As I said in my answer, you get that from `GetDlgCtrlID(lParam)`.  As a reminder, when using `find()` check the return value.

Comment: Actually, the id already is the key.

Comment: std::map<unsigned long, X3D::Windows::Control*> m_controls;

Comment: Yes, but your code here used a counter.  If you're going to use `find()`, DO fetch the ID, and don't loop.

Comment: Trying this: if (frm.getControls().at(i)->getHandle() == (HWND)lParam)  Apparently it didn't like that. I'll try GetDlgCtrlID(lParam).

Comment: Updating above...

Comment: The new chunk looks correct, except that you still dereference the result of `find()` without checking if it succeeded.

Comment: I tried all kinds of checking but none succeeding during compile time. I guess I'm not 100% sure how to check if find() succeeded.

Comment: `auto& controls = frm.getControls(); auto it = controls.find(id);  if (it != controls.end()) { auto ctrl = it->second; }`

Comment: Thanks. This is honestly the third time I cried out for help on the Win32 API this week. These are very basic things (or should be): setting a text's color, hovering over a label, etc. This can take seconds to achieve in C#; instead I'm dealing with cryptic multi-line code to do something so basic instead of working on my application. The problem isn't much of C++, but it is relying on old C-based libraries. I'm glad I learned the Win32 API enough to appreciate the underlying code, but I'm declaring my July 4th independence from it and moving forward to C# for increased productivity.

Comment: Usage of `std::map` has nothing to do with the Win32 API, that is 100% ISO Standard C++.  Enjoy C#, I do.  But if you wanted to spend time working on your application why did you decide to make your own C++ widget library instead of using one of the existing ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` is sent multiple times, you can choose to take different actions depending on which child window is generating it.

As shown [on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/wm-ctlcolorstatic), the `lParam` that arrives with the message is the `HWND` for the control.  Compare it directly, or `GetDlgCtrlID()` if you want to work with dialog item IDs.

No need to do anything special in the subclass wndproc, because `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` is sent to the parent window.

But there is no message to send to change the color or font, because the `STATIC` window class doesn't use a permanent device context per label (which is a good thing, because many programs have a lot of labels).  So the text configuration like color and font need to be reapplied to the DC each time it is borrowed from the pool.  `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` is sent to the parent window at the ideal time to do this.

If your setter for the color is called, be sure to use `InvalidateRect()` to trigger a repaint.  That repaint will send `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` again, giving you the opportunity to act on your updated color.

Comment: Good points so far. See my update.

Comment: Per my answer to your other question, once you associate your `Control*` pointers with their `HWND`s, your `find()` loop becomes unnecessary. These messages tell you which child  `HWND` is being painted, so you will have direct access to its `Label` object to know which color and font to apply. In fact, you might want to consider updating your classes to reflect notification messages back to the `HWND`s that generate them, so your `Control` classes can handle their own notifications and not be handled by their parent windows. That will make your classes more self contained and easier to manage