# Set HWND TXT Color

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to give a color for 1 single `HWND` in my win32 api..
So far I managed to give color for txt/background but that's for all the static `HWND`s I have as follows:

```
HWND txtview1
HWND txtview2

HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)wParam;

case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0, 0, 150));
    SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0, 230, 0));
    return (INT_PTR)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0255, 255));
    break;
```

I know it gets applied to wParam which is the whole thing..
But I want to apply it to 1 single HWND called (txtview1) not to txtview2 too
I tried:

```
HDC hdcStatic = GetDC(txtview1);
```

but it doesn't take affect, any hint is much appreciated.

Comment: Please refer to the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) how to format your posts here correctly. I did this this time for you.

Comment: Look at the documentation again. There is a second parameter to the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message. Also, you are leaking the brush.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I have five Win32 static controls, how can I set one of them with a specific foreground color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165490/if-i-have-five-win32-static-controls-how-can-i-set-one-of-them-with-a-specific)

Answer (score 5):

You need to handle this message with checking if lParam equals to HWND you need

```
if ( (HWND)lParam == txtview1 )
```

Otherwise, just fall back to DefWindowProc

Comment: Oh my god, worked.
It took me 6 hours to figure this piece of line, Thank you Alexander.